# How to call gesture swipe method from another method in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have this gesture swipe method that I want to call from another method using

[self performSelector:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)
               withObject:nil afterDelay:10];

I can't figure out the syntax to put in the **@selector()**

any help is appreciated. here's my code:

```
 - (IBAction)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender { 
        if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
            NSLog(@"swipe left");
            TutorialMenuViewController *tutorialMenuViewController = [[TutorialMenuViewController alloc]
                                                          initWithNibName:@"TutorialMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:tutorialMenuViewController animated:YES];
            [tutorialMenuViewController release];
        }
    }
```

Comment: you will have to register swipeGestureRecognizer for respective view.

Comment: thanks. what would be the syntax for the following?   [self performSelector:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)
                   withObject:nil afterDelay:10];

Comment: What's the issue? You are calling it correctly although you will not get into the if statement as you are passing a `nil` object. So the if statement looks like this and evaluates to false `[[nil direction] == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to present `TutorialMenuViewController` either on a gesture or time delay you would be better off just abstracting its presentation out into a different method

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender { 
    if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        [self presentTutorial];
    }
}

- (void)presentTutorial;
{
    TutorialMenuViewController *tutorialMenuViewController = [[TutorialMenuViewController alloc]
                                                      initWithNibName:@"TutorialMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tutorialMenuViewController animated:YES];
    [tutorialMenuViewController release];
}
```

Now you can simply call

```
[self performSelector:@selector(presentTutorial) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender { 
if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
    NSLog(@"swipe left");
    //TutorialMenuViewController *tutorialMenuViewController = [[TutorialMenuViewController alloc]
    //                                                        initWithNibName:@"TutorialMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:tutorialMenuViewController animated:YES];
    //[tutorialMenuViewController release];
}
}
```

Called it like this:

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe  =  [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:nil action:nil];
[leftSwipe setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
[self performSelector:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:) withObject:leftSwipe afterDelay:1];
[leftSwipe release];
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of unnecessary work creating and configuring an object just to pass an `if` statement. It also promotes bad design because now the calling method needs to know the internal details of how the method it is calling works.

Comment: Surely the best solution is to guide people away from bad design, whether you ask new questions or make new suggestions. Yes this would be the way of actually hacking together what the OP wanted but is it not the right solution to their problem. I don't mean to sound harsh,I'm just trying to give constructive feedback for you to keep in mind when helping the next person.

Comment: I agree. You are not being harsh at all. But one doubt, there could be a situation where I don't have the source code of **handleSwipeGesture**. In that case what should I do?

Comment: If you couldn't see the source you wouldn't have known that the OP needed to set `direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft` ;) In which case you would probably just probe for more information by commenting below their post